# Monitor executed search queries in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to create a pipeline for **monitoring user executed queries** in elasticsearch.

*I followed this (somehow dated?) tutorial*

*https://www.elastic.co/blog/monitoring-the-search-queries*

I successfully installed logstash, packetbeat and kibana. Both applications are configured locally right now and I am able to access all of them. I verified existence of new indices in elastisearch with a name `logstash-2020.04.06-000001`. I use pretty much same config as given in tutorial, the only difference is that my ip addresses are local, in this case, I am using `127.0.0.1` in place of `10.255.4.165`, simply because it wasn't working otherwise. All applications work on default ports.

Whole setup seems to work perfectly fine, but I don't see any queries being saved anywhere.

Moreover, I cannot create Index Pattern in Kibana to track user queries. I can see that index exists both in *Rest API* and Kibana *Index Managment*, however, it's an empty index, without any documents. I already tried to restart all of services after configuration using systemd.

I am using **Elasticsearch 7.6.2.**

How can I fix it?

Is there maybe other solution for logging executed queries?

I don't necessarily need Kibana visualization, but I need to know user queries to fix relevance scores for results.

**Packetbeat config file, /etc/packetbeat/packetbeat.yml:**

```
# Select the network interfaces to sniff the data. You can use the "any"
# keyword to sniff on all connected interfaces.
interfaces:
device: any

http:   
# Configure the ports where to listen for HTTP traffic. You can disable    
# the HTTP protocol by commenting out the list of ports.   
  ports: [9200]   
  send_request: true   
  include_body_for: ["application/json", "x-www-form-urlencoded"]

#elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  # Scheme and port can be left out and will be set to the default (http and 9200)
  # In case you specify and additional path, the scheme is required: http://localhost:9200/path
  # IPv6 addresses should always be defined as: https://[2001:db8::1]:9200
  # hosts: ["Localhost:9200"]

### Logstash as output
logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["127.0.0.1:5044"]

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["127.0.0.1:5044"]
```

**This is my packetbeat console output:**

```
user@host:/usr/share/packetbeat$ sudo ./bin/packetbeat -e -c /etc/packetbeat/packetbeat.yml -d "publish"
2020-04-07T15:59:50.855+0200    INFO    instance/beat.go:622    Home path: [/usr/share/packetbeat/bin] Config path: [/usr/share/packetbeat/bin] Data path: [/usr/share/packetbeat/bin/data] Logs path: [/usr/share/packetbeat/bin/logs]
2020-04-07T15:59:50.873+0200    INFO    instance/beat.go:630    Beat ID: 25a0570e-3395-4a8b-8dcf-38c19560eb44
2020-04-07T15:59:50.897+0200    INFO    [api]   api/server.go:62    Starting stats endpoint
2020-04-07T15:59:50.906+0200    INFO    [api]   api/server.go:64    Metrics endpoint listening on: 127.0.0.1:5066 (configured: localhost)
2020-04-07T15:59:50.907+0200    INFO    [seccomp]   seccomp/seccomp.go:124  Syscall filter successfully installed
2020-04-07T15:59:50.907+0200    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:958    Beat info   {"system_info": {"beat": {"path": {"config": "/usr/share/packetbeat/bin", "data": "/usr/share/packetbeat/bin/data", "home": "/usr/share/packetbeat/bin", "logs": "/usr/share/packetbeat/bin/logs"}, "type": "packetbeat", "uuid": "25a0570e-3395-4a8b-8dcf-38c19560eb44"}}}
2020-04-07T15:59:50.907+0200    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:967    Build info  {"system_info": {"build": {"commit": "d57bcf8684602e15000d65b75afcd110e2b12b59", "libbeat": "7.6.2", "time": "2020-03-26T05:09:32.000Z", "version": "7.6.2"}}}
2020-04-07T15:59:50.907+0200    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:970    Go runtime info {"system_info": {"go": {"os":"linux","arch":"amd64","max_procs":8,"version":"go1.13.8"}}}
2020-04-07T15:59:50.908+0200    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:974    Host info   {"system_info": {"host": {"architecture":"x86_64","boot_time":"2020-04-07T11:24:50+02:00","containerized":false,"name":"host","ip":["127.0.0.1/8","::1/128","192.168.1.11/24","fe80::dacb:8aff:fe80:d3f5/64","172.17.0.1/16"],"kernel_version":"4.9.0-12-amd64","mac":["XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"],"os":{"family":"debian","platform":"debian","name":"Debian GNU/Linux","version":"9 (stretch)","major":9,"minor":0,"patch":0,"codename":"stretch"},"timezone":"CEST","timezone_offset_sec":7200,"id":"414bf25d70c54332b8cf4d2a82ee0108"}}}
2020-04-07T15:59:50.908+0200    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1003   Process info    {"system_info": {"process": {"capabilities": {"inheritable":null,"permitted":["chown","dac_override","dac_read_search","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","linux_immutable","net_bind_service","net_broadcast","net_admin","net_raw","ipc_lock","ipc_owner","sys_module","sys_rawio","sys_chroot","sys_ptrace","sys_pacct","sys_admin","sys_boot","sys_nice","sys_resource","sys_time","sys_tty_config","mknod","lease","audit_write","audit_control","setfcap","mac_override","mac_admin","syslog","wake_alarm","block_suspend","audit_read"],"effective":["chown","dac_override","dac_read_search","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","linux_immutable","net_bind_service","net_broadcast","net_admin","net_raw","ipc_lock","ipc_owner","sys_module","sys_rawio","sys_chroot","sys_ptrace","sys_pacct","sys_admin","sys_boot","sys_nice","sys_resource","sys_time","sys_tty_config","mknod","lease","audit_write","audit_control","setfcap","mac_override","mac_admin","syslog","wake_alarm","block_suspend","audit_read"],"bounding":["chown","dac_override","dac_read_search","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","linux_immutable","net_bind_service","net_broadcast","net_admin","net_raw","ipc_lock","ipc_owner","sys_module","sys_rawio","sys_chroot","sys_ptrace","sys_pacct","sys_admin","sys_boot","sys_nice","sys_resource","sys_time","sys_tty_config","mknod","lease","audit_write","audit_control","setfcap","mac_override","mac_admin","syslog","wake_alarm","block_suspend","audit_read"],"ambient":null}, "cwd": "/usr/share/packetbeat", "exe": "/usr/share/packetbeat/bin/packetbeat", "name": "packetbeat", "pid": 9679, "ppid": 9678, "seccomp": {"mode":"filter"}, "start_time": "2020-04-07T15:59:50.259+0200"}}}
2020-04-07T15:59:50.908+0200    INFO    instance/beat.go:298    Setup Beat: packetbeat; Version: 7.6.2
2020-04-07T15:59:50.908+0200    INFO    [publisher] pipeline/module.go:110  Beat name: host
2020-04-07T15:59:50.908+0200    INFO    procs/procs.go:105  Process watcher disabled
2020-04-07T15:59:50.924+0200    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:118  Starting metrics logging every 30s
2020-04-07T15:59:50.924+0200    INFO    instance/beat.go:439    packetbeat start running.
2020-04-07T16:00:20.926+0200    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:145  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s    {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":40,"time":{"ms":44}},"total":{"ticks":160,"time":{"ms":172},"value":160},"user":{"ticks":120,"time":{"ms":128}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":4096,"soft":1024},"open":8},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"0634aeb9-6358-4947-a908-7043973876dc","uptime":{"ms":30132}},"memstats":{"gc_next":39455344,"memory_alloc":21608032,"memory_total":26051720,"rss":66273280},"runtime":{"goroutines":14}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0}},"output":{"type":"logstash"},"pipeline":{"clients":0,"events":{"active":0}}},"system":{"cpu":{"cores":8},"load":{"1":0.5,"15":0.64,"5":0.75,"norm":{"1":0.0625,"15":0.08,"5":0.0938}}}}}}
```

**Logstash config file, /usr/share/logstash/es-first-config.conf:**

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter {
  if "search" in [request]{
    grok {
      match => { "request" => ".*\n\{(?<query_body>.*)"} 
    }
    grok {
      match => { "path" => "\/(?<index>.*)\/_search"}     
    }
    if [index] {
    } 
    else {
      mutate {
        add_field  => { "index" => "All" }
      }
    }
    mutate {
      update  => { "query_body" => "{%{query_body}" }
    }
  }
}
output {
  if "search" in [request] and "ignore_unmapped" not in [query_body]{
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "127.0.0.1:9200"
    }
  }
}
```

**This is my logstash console output:**

```
user@host:/usr/share/logstash$ sudo ./bin/logstash --path.settings /etc/logstash -f es-first-config.conf
Sending Logstash logs to /var/log/logstash which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2020-04-07T15:58:33,546][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2020-04-07T15:58:33,731][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.6.2"}
[2020-04-07T15:58:35,916][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 33 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 20 keys and 40 values 
[2020-04-07T15:58:37,443][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://127.0.0.1:9200/]}}
[2020-04-07T15:58:37,630][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://127.0.0.1:9200/"}
[2020-04-07T15:58:37,688][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
[2020-04-07T15:58:37,694][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2020-04-07T15:58:37,789][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//127.0.0.1:9200"]}
[2020-04-07T15:58:37,850][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using default mapping template
[2020-04-07T15:58:37,935][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"index_patterns"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s", "number_of_shards"=>1, "index.lifecycle.name"=>"logstash-policy", "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias"=>"logstash"}, "mappings"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}
[2020-04-07T15:58:38,108][WARN ][org.logstash.instrument.metrics.gauge.LazyDelegatingGauge][main] A gauge metric of an unknown type (org.jruby.specialized.RubyArrayOneObject) has been created for key: cluster_uuids. This may result in invalid serialization.  It is recommended to log an issue to the responsible developer/development team.
[2020-04-07T15:58:38,114][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000, "pipeline.sources"=>["/usr/share/logstash/es-first-config.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x7437b24 run>"}
[2020-04-07T15:58:39,246][INFO ][logstash.inputs.beats    ][main] Beats inputs: Starting input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:5044"}
[2020-04-07T15:58:39,314][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2020-04-07T15:58:39,388][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2020-04-07T15:58:39,480][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.Server][main] Starting server on port: 5044
[2020-04-07T15:58:39,762][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just like you, but a little more advanced. The problem occurs for the following, you are missing this piece of code:

```
packetbeat.flows:
   timeout: 30s
   period: 10s

processors:
- add_cloud_metadata: ~
```

obviously packetbeat has to run on the same elastic node to capture port 9200

Without this, it doesn't start sending data to logstash, I don't know why, but try it (level stackoverflow, sorry)

Once the data is sent and you see it, you will have the body in a field, here comes the following:

You will need to amplify the capacity (using vector) of several fields so that it will not give error (mappings index--> request and http ... request field)

Later, this collapses my nodes, and there I am. Looking for updated information on monitoring search queries in elasticsearch in 2020.